# Inherit div height from parent with absolute position

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to achieve this kind of layout with pure CSS:

[image: Layout]

The gradient in the background is 100% the width of the browser window. The inner text is inside a 1000px div, centered inside the browser window. Now I want the text to define the height of the gradient. And here is the problem: The gradient is positioned absolute (`left: 0px; width: 100%`), but the text is inside another div.

I've tried some things with `display:table;` and `display:table-cell;` but once I put the gradient div to `position:absolute` it doesn't inherit the height of the text div.

Anyone a solution how to achieve this in pure CSS without javascript?

**EDIT:**

I'm sorry I forgot to mention that **the gradient isn't the problem** (I' using css3). And furthermore I also forgot to add the code: http://jsfiddle.net/kxu8N/1/

Comment: Your HTML and CSS would help. :)

Comment: I'm guessing absolute positioning inside a relative container but without the code it's quite hard to see what needs to be done.

Comment: Have you tried using css3 gradients?

Comment: I made some edits, hope that helps

Comment: ... So... instead of fiddling with absolute positioning, why not just put `#blue` inside of `#blue-background` ?

Comment: Or better yet, get rid of `#blue-background` and give `#blue` the gradient background...

Comment: That would be possible if the ``#blue-background`` doesn't have to have the width of the browser window. And the ``#blue`` div is centered to the browser window. So when resizing the browser window the ``#blue-background`` should always be 100% of the window and the ``#blue`` div should always be centered.

Comment: I made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kxu8N/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I didn't find any solution, I hacked it. Cause my content gets added dynamically through javascript, I added the content two times. The first time visible inside the overlaying div (over the blue background), and the second time inside the blue background. With `visibility: hidden` I hide all the divs inside the blue background.

And because both divs got the same content, they get the same height. Not beautiful, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely-positioned elements are not part of the layout flow, therefore they cannot inherit dimensional information from parent elements.

You should be using a CSS background image (or a CSS3 gradient) on the element wrapping your text to give you the gradient instead of using a separate element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css3 background-size property to scale the height of the gradient. Set the height to auto on a div with the gradient as its background.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer without knowing your HTML structure: http://jsfiddle.net/8xagQ/1/

```
.gradient{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,119,255,0) 0%,rgba(0,119,255,1) 25%,rgba(0,119,255,1) 50%,rgba(0,119,255,1) 75%,rgba(0,119,255,0) 100%);

    margin:10px 0;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px 0;
}​
```

Note that I only included the gradient instructions for webkit.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
 <head>
<style type="text/css">
p,span{
    margin-left:20px;
}

#logo{
    font-weight: bold;
    height:100px;
}
#slogan{
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,119,255,0) 0%,rgba(0,200,230,15) 25%,rgba(0,200,230,15) 50%,rgba(0,200,230,15) 75%,rgba(0,119,255,0) 100%);}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="logo">
        <p>Logo</p>
    </div>
    <div id="slogan">
        <span>some text that defines hieght of this</span>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my Case I move your blue into your gradient. that way, once you add more line, line of text it will increate automaticaly

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="outer">
      <div id="blue-background">
         <div class="span3" id="blue">
          Here is my content<br>
             and this content should define the height of the underlying #blue-background <br />
             and if we are adding more and more and more
          </div>     
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Then to the text into it I change few setting in the CSS

```
#blue {
  z-index: 1;
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: thx, but as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/r3NsD/1/ the content gets aligned to the left of the window. But I want to keep it in the ``#outer`` div (the text should wrap inside the 200px outer div and be aligned to the left side of the outer div)